# Stuck in read-only mode

Tags: read-only

I am new to Linux so please bear with me.

I run Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-155-generic x86_64) on a partition of my hard drive. Multiple things happened :

- I filled up that partition while downloading a rather large file, as i got notifications about having 0 MO space left.
- used command `sudo apt autoremove` and a bunch of apps got deleted before i realised it and stopped the process. i don’t know the extent of that damage.

I shut down the computer.

A day after, I booted my Linux partition up, and I got in read-only mode. I managed to log in and clear up my Download folders to make some space. Shut the computer down, turned it on, and still read-only mode. Computer is not connected to the Internet.

I tried opening up Baobab, and i got this error :

`Unable to init server: Impossible to connect : connection refused`
`(baobab:1689): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display`

I do not know what to do to get out of read-only mode. I don’t have important files on that partition, so I can do a factory reset on it, but I’d rather not.

Comment: If you were able to delete files from Downloads, you were not in read-only mode. Please verify your claims.

Comment: `autoremove` has nothing to do with cleaning large downloaded files. Please provide more detail; your narrative is confusing and appears self-contradictory.